# Family vacation!​

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

You and your family are taking a vacation planned by your parents, famous violinists! But they also love cryptography and give you a chance to figure out where you are going beforehand! They sent you this text:

> `9z35s9h1605v`

Can you figure it out in time for the vacation?

Hint 1:

> You may be eating a lot of this on your vacation:
>
>  [image: hashbrowns]

Comment: I'll probably post an answer soon...

Comment: @58672 I just started trying, be patient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to

> [Broken Bow, Nebraska](https://cityofbrokenbow.org/).

You can ascertain this by

> interpreting the the text as a [geohash](http://geohash.org/9z35s9h1605v) which points to Broken Bow, Nebraska. As a clue of whittling down the final location if necessary, your parents are famous violinists and a **bow** (as in Broken **Bow**) is used to play violin. Finally, the hint shows a picture of **hash**browns (as in geo**hash**).

Whether or not that's the best place for a family vacation, I do not know... but you can decide for yourself! :):)

Comment: It looks like that site accepts literally *any* string of letters and numbers. What was supposed to point us to that in the puzzle?

Comment: @Deusovi -- Some combinations of numbers and letters are not valid geohashes... But yes, virtually any combination can get you to a certain lat/long.